# Tablet detection with detect mobile browser script?

Tags: php, mobile

I'm using the php-version of detectmobilebrowsers.com to detect mobile browsers.

I'd like to add tablets to this script and it's mentioned on the about page that I should add the following to the first regex: |android|ipad|playbook|silk

I don't know where to place it?

I'd allso like to know if there's a way to only check for tablets using this script. Is this possible or should I discard the use of the above mentioned script and use another detection script for my purposes?

I have looked into other alternatives: http://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/PHP/mdetect.php

and mobiledetect.net

Any thoughts on them? What is the best solution to use?

Kind regards
Johan

Comment: If you can, I think you should do this using [css media queries](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/).

Comment: or search in general for "responsive layouts" and you will find a lot of material.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the replies. I'm using responsive layouts. The things is I have a video playing in an colorbox iframe and this colorbox is not displayed on mobile phones. I'd like this colorbox to be deisplayed on tablets but not exactly the same as on a regular computer. That's why I'd like to use some what of an mobile detection script.

Comment: You should avoid detecting specific browsers/devices, particularly in the mobile world where things change so quickly that pretty much any browser detection will be out of date really quickly and give false results. Also, if you're trying to distinguish between phones and tablets, what do you do about devices like [this](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/08/14/review_samsung_mega_6_android_smartphone/) that fit half-way between the normal definitions? And what about MS Surface devices, which are tablets but come with a keyboard and run the exact same Win8 OS and browsers as desktop machines?

Comment: Thanks @Spudley. Intressting comment you made there. The problem I have is that I'm using the Vimeo froogaloop API and colorbox to display an iframe playing an video. Since autoplay is not possible on tablets I'd like to have a check in some way.

Is there any good way to check this? What should I do?

Answer (score 8):

To answer the first part of your question: You add it right before the first "/i". The current PHP version of the script would become:

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
?>
```

Comment: What is the best way to use this same code in an IF statement so that it first checks if it is a tablet, and if not, then it checks to see if it's a phone.  What I tried didn't work.